# Compile Qt from source cannot use OpenSSL along with OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, openssl

I'm in confuse right now.
I've just tried compiling Qt 5.3.1 libs with MinGW 4.8.2

Previously, I managed to build OpenSSL. And I want to use it for compiling Qt with -openssl.
But, I've got a little problem. When I use this configure command:

```
configure -opensource -confirm-license -platform win32-g++ \
-make libs -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -no-icu -qt-zlib \
-qt-pcre -no-iconv -nomake examples -nomake tests \
-opengl desktop -no-dbus -strip -plugin-sql-sqlite \
-skip qtconnectivity -skip qtlocation -skip qtsensors \
-openssl -I "D:\openssl\include" -L "D:\openssl\lib"
```

the configuration gives error like:

```
You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL, QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL in
d:/Develop/Qt-Lib/5.3.1/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-g++.
```

but, I don't know where is the OpenGL include dir to be passed as the argument.

Then, when I remove the -openssl argument, the configure is okay.

```
configure -opensource -confirm-license -platform win32-g++ \
-make libs -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -no-icu -qt-zlib \
-qt-pcre -no-iconv -nomake examples -nomake tests \
-opengl desktop -no-dbus -strip -plugin-sql-sqlite \
-skip qtconnectivity -skip qtlocation -skip qtsensors
```

Please give me idea, what's my err?

Comment: I guess the -I and -L option completely override any other search paths found by configure. So either give full search paths that cover all the other libraries as well, or omit those options and somehow differently tell the build where to locate OpenSSL; note that since this is a custom OpenSSL build it's acceptable to manually place the OpenSSL headers in libraries in the Qt build tree.

Comment: Is it okay to put openssl dir to the system's PATH, @datenwolf?

Comment: Does it work? Yes. Should you do it? **NO!**; doing that just leads to a lot of pain in the long run. BT;DT when I was young and unexperienced.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've decided to remove the `-opessl` option, and I got another problem when the build came to `qtbase/lib/libQt5OpenGL.a ...` in the `src/opengl` directory. One of the errors: `make[1] *** [sub-src-make_first] error 2`