# Compiling Qt 5.3.1 from source error at qprintsupport

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, compilation, mingw

I'm not sure whether or not this question has a causality with [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833108/compile-qt-from-source-cannot-use-openssl-along-with-opengl).

So, I compiled Qt 5.3.1 from source with MinGW 4.8.2. The build stopped at `qtbase/src/printsupport` directory, as you can see the image below:

[image: error: enumeration value 'PPK_CustomBase' not handled in switch]

Is it a bug or something at `qtbase/src/printsupport/kernel/qprintengine_win.cpp` file? Then, should I just report it to the developer?

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248393/disable-warnings-being-treated-as-errorscc1-exe) it give you a hint. Probably somewhere you use this key `-Werror` in make files implicitly or explicitly when start compilation with gcc. If I correct understand error in that switch operation must be `default:` statement or `case PPK_CustomBase:` statement.

Comment: I'm sorry, I left it for a while. I'll try it when using windows

Comment: I still don't get it how could I use `-Werror` explicitly or implicitly. While, I've found a comment in `qprintengine_win.cpp`, at the error scope: `// No default so that compiler will complain if new keys added and not handled in this engine`. Does it explain the issue?

Comment: Strange, I look to my source files and I find `case PPK_CustomBase:` at the error scope. Based on this that error should not occur even if you use `-Werror`.

Answer (score 1):

miraiE,

If you will notice in your output: cc1plus.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
This is, as was mentioned before, a warning that is stopping the compile process as an error.

You should be able to run you configure.bat script again, with the option -no-warnings-are-errors.
Then re-run your make.exe to get past this, and other warnings, from stopping the build.

Details of the specific configure options below:

> ../qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.1/configure --help |grep -i warn
>
> -silent ............ Reduce the build output so that warnings and errors
>
> -no-warnings-are-errors Make warnings be treated normally
>
> -warnings-are-errors  Make warnings be treated as errors

I hope this helps!